# CRM 2013 Get CRM URL via Custom Workflow

Tags: c#, workflow, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a requirement for getting a CRM URL via a custom workflow to use in the next step which is to send an email. The reason for this is to differentiate to users which server this email has come from (UAT/Live).

I have been trying to use HTTPContext route as advised from this site https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31ff567d-65ea-4385-a764-68a2121ae8c0/ms-crm-2011-get-path-of-crm-server-url-in-plugin?forum=crmdevelopment but the result I get back is useless as I am I am only receiving an "/" back.

Does anyone know what to do from this point or why this may not be working?

Comment: This would be not a good answer and direct answer, but have you tried creating a new field and save the url in it with javascript then you can use it in workflow.

Comment: @tottotech i thought about this however the workflow runs from many different entities (all the activities) so i would rather stay away from this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coming up with a solution by using the environment.machinename to pull through the server name. From there i could determine which production server the workflow had been run through and passed a string containing, dev, uat or live to the output to use in my activity emails.

Be aware i had to register the workflow without it being in sandbox mode. Hope this helps somebody in the future.

Answer (score 3):

This can't be accomplished, in a supported manner, without creating a connection to the CRM Discovery Service, which requires that you supply credentials. The organization service, available in the workflow does not have a method for discovering the organization's URL.

You have two options:

1) Pass it to the workflow as a parameter using the `InputParameter` code attribute on your `CodeActivity`.

2) Create (if you don't already have one) a configuration entity to store the URL and retrieve it in your code.

If you don't really need the URL (i.e., you are not creating a link) then you could just query the `Organization` entity for the `Name` attribute. That will give you the Organization's name - which would be the only unique part of the URL. This would allow you to indicate to the user if the Email was coming from UAT or Prod.

Comment: Hi Nick thanks for your feedback. I am going to try using environment.machinename and see if this will get me back the result I want as our dev, uat, prod are all on different server and as long as I can get back the server name I will be able to differentiate between the environments, I will provide result once i have tried to implement

Answer (score 0):

This was an extremely old question but I came across it while attempting to do something similar.

I found that there is a `RetrieveCurrentOrganizationRequest` request which was introduced in v9. This will work in sandboxed plugins.

You can use this to retrieve the endpoint urls like so

```
var currentOrg = base.OrgService.Execute(
  new RetrieveCurrentOrganizationRequest()
) as RetrieveCurrentOrganizationResponse;

var url = currentOrg.Detail.Endpoints
  .Where(e => e.Key == EndpointType.WebApplication)
  .FirstOrDefault()
  .Value;
```

More information here: [RetrieveCurrentOrganizationRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.retrievecurrentorganizationrequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9)

When I used it, I found that there are 3 available URLs in the `Endpoints` collection:

1. Web Application
2. Organization Data Service
3. Organization Service

Relevant to CRM 2013 (which the OP was using at the time), there is also the `RetrieveOrganizationRequest` class which does the same as above; however you have to specify the Organization (and some other information)